# SemanticImport extremely slow with "Number" format

Tags: performance-tuning, import, csv-format, semantic-matching

With the following definition:

```
col = "num\n" <> StringRiffle[Table[i, {i, 1000}], "\n"];
```

I do not understand why the `"Number"` format is *two orders of magnitude* slower than the others:

```
Table[
    Timing[
        SemanticImportString[
            col, <|"num" -> format|>
        ];
    ],
    {format, {"Integer", Automatic, "Number"}}
]

(* {{0.03125, Null}, {0.046875, Null}, {4.70313, Null}} *)
```

Comment: I suspect that the `"Number"` format has to run through a lot more possible interpretations for the same input than the `"Integer"` format. As for `Automatic`, the "Possible Issues" section of the docs for `SemanticImportString` say that "Automatic type selection chooses from a smaller set of interpretations rather than specifying a type explicitly", so perhaps once again a reduced number of choices makes the process significantly faster.